# How to use branded string as an index to a Record type

Tags: typescript

My strings take a certain format so I often type them to be sure they are in a particular format. For example I check my strings are prefixed with `foo`. How can I use a branded string as an index to a record?

```
type Foo = string & { _fooBrand: undefined }
type T = Record<Foo, string>
const f = (a: T, b: Foo) => {
  const c = a[b] // Type 'Foo' cannot be used as an index type.
}
```

Comment: Why not use a [`Map<BrandedString, unknown>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)?

Comment: @ZouJeff because I want to serialize to IndexedDB and I can't store Map directly into IDB

Comment: Can you clarify what "taking a certain format" means? If the set of values known up front, a union of literal types would allow for better compile time checking.

Comment: Take a certain format means they have an exact prefix @meriton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to work this one out by creating some helper functions caked in conditional types. You can then use the helper functions `get(), set(), keys(), values()`

```
export const get = <T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, key: K): RecordValue<T> | undefined =>
  (obj as any)[key] as RecordValue<T> | undefined

export const set = <T, K extends keyof T, V extends RecordValue<T>>(
  obj: T,
  key: K,
  value: V
): CheckRecordKeyValue<T, K, V> => ((obj as any)[key] = value as any)

export const keys = <T>(obj: T): RecordKey<T>[] => Object.keys(obj) as RecordKey<T>[]

export const values = <T>(obj: T): RecordValue<T>[] => Object.values(obj) as RecordValue<T>[]

export type RecordKey<T> = T extends Record<infer K, infer V> ? K : never
export type RecordValue<T> = T extends Record<infer K, infer V>
  ? K extends keyof T
    ? V
    : never
  : never
export type CheckRecordKeyValue<T, K, V> = T extends Record<infer K2, infer V2>
  ? K extends K2
    ? V extends V2
      ? undefined
      : never
    : never
  : never
```

code now becomes

```
type Foo = string & { _fooBrand: undefined }
type T = Record<Foo, string>
const f = (a: T, b: Foo) => {
  const c = get(a, b) // 
  set(a, b, 'asdf')
}
```